# Is it possible to interactively select/deselect grouped elements within a layout?

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts

Within ArcGIS Pro, once I group a bunch of layout elements such as city labels and their associated point symbols, I can't then individually select a city label without the system grabbing the entire group for editing or moving (for example the other 10 cities I have with associated point symbols). Since grouping items is essential to organization, especially on more complex layouts, I believe I am missing how to do this.

Is there a way around this in settings or someplace else?

Answer (score 1):

You can  easily access the properties of individual elements that have been grouped via the TOC. Simply right click on the element in the group and chose properties as shown below.

[image: TOC]

Comment: Thanks, though this doesn't help if I need to select things interactively on the map, such as callouts of a certain color amongst many other callouts, etc. I could properly name every TOC item, but it still doesn't carry the same effect as being able to select within the actual map while doing work.

Comment: Have you tried a "long click" on the item, that works for me.

Comment: No luck there either!